# Asymptotic expansion as $N\to\infty$ involving $\frac{\sin Nx}{\sin x}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics

Let $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R$ be fixed, and let $N\in \mathbb N$. I am interested in the large $N$ behavior of
$$I = \frac 1N \sum_{k\in \frac{2\pi}{N}\mathbb Z} e^{i\frac{N-1}{2} (k-\alpha)} \frac{\sin\left( N \frac{k-\alpha}{2}\right)}{\sin\frac{k-\alpha}{2}} \frac{e^{iN(k+\beta)}-1}{k+\beta} \chi(k).$$
Here, $\chi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a smooth and compactly supported function.

I have the following naive argument. Using the formula
$$\frac{\sin tx}{x} \stackrel{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \pi\delta(x),$$
we formally take the continuum limit as
$$I = \underbrace{\frac 1N \sum_{k\in \frac{2\pi}{N}\mathbb Z}}_{\frac{1}{2\pi} \int dk} e^{i\frac{N-1}{2} (k-\alpha)} \underbrace{\frac{\sin\left( N \frac{k-\alpha}{2}\right)}{\sin\frac{k-\alpha}{2}}}_{2\pi\delta(k-\alpha)} \frac{e^{iN(k+\beta)}-1}{k+\beta} \chi(k).$$
One concern is that $e^{i\frac{N-1}{2} (k-\alpha)}$ does not have a limit, and oscillates too rapidly, possibly not compatible with the limit that gives the Dirac delta function. If we accept this,
$$I = \frac{e^{iN(\alpha+\beta)}-1}{\alpha+\beta} \chi(\alpha).$$
Hence, $I$, viewed as a function of $\beta$, is sharply peaked at $\beta=-\alpha$, of peak height $O(N)$ and peak width $O(1/N)$.

Can we formulate a more rigorous derivation? I just wonder whether my naive argument is right or wrong.

Finally, I remark that my summand is a product of:
$$e^{i\frac{N-1}{2} (k-\alpha)} \frac{\sin\left( N \frac{k-\alpha}{2}\right)}{\sin\frac{k-\alpha}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{i(k-\alpha)n}, \quad \textrm{and} \quad i\int_0^N e^{i(k+\beta)x} dx = \frac{e^{iN(k+\beta)}-1}{k+\beta}.$$